# Basic ImageView breaks app in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

As soon as I add an ImageView to the layout, the app cannot run. When the code for the ImageView in activity_main.xml is removed, the app works. I've seen the app break in both Pixel 3a API 33, and my physical Pixel 5 device
Here are the main files:
activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.kt:

```
package com.example.test_custom_toast

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
            val inflater = layoutInflater
            val layout: View = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.custom_toast,
                findViewById<View>(R.id.clToast) as ViewGroup
            )
            val toast = Toast(this)
            toast.apply {
                duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                setContentView(layout)
                show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have another layout, but since I can't even get to it, I posting code seems irrelevant

Comment: If your app crashes, you could find some error messages from [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/games/optimize/crash) .

Comment: share your logcat error , which helps to understand the issue

Comment: Try removing `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"` from `<Button` and let me know if it works.

Comment: My apologies, it seems after I shut down my computer last night its now working for the ImageView. I'm still having some issues with the Inflator, it states `null cannot be cast to non-null type android.view.ViewGroup` clToast is a constraintLayout, with just an image and a text views inside the file custom_toast.xml

Comment: Some quick research brought me to change the `findViewById` to null, and then swap `setContentView` to `setView`. `setView` is considered deprecated though, so at some point I'd like to research alternatives